# Ajax+php получение данных

Tags: ajax, php

Здравствуйте.

Никогда раньше не работал с ajax'ом. Сейчас нужно сделать подгрузку данных черех ajax, и тут же столкнулся с проблемой. Почитав принцип работы ajax сделал следующий код:

```
$.ajax({
 url: './ajax.php',
 type: "GET",
 data: "showall",
 success: function(response){
  $(".foreach").html(response);
  $(".link").attr({"value":""})
 }
});
```

Отправил GET'ом значение showall на сервере подхватил его PHP.

```
if(isset($_GET['showall'])) {
 // много кода :)
 $a = "aaa";
 $b = "bbb";
 $c = "ccc";
}
```

После отработки PHP кода я генерирую шаблонную часть и передаю её обратно в блок с классом "foreach". С этим проблем нет.

Теперь вопрос: как мне в ajax ответе получить данные из PHP переменных $a,$b,$c заполненных в ходе работы скрипта.
В данном случае нужно вставить содержимое переменной допустим $a в значение value

```
$(".link").attr({"value":""})
```

т.е. мне нужно понять как передается содержимое PHP переменных в JS для дальнейшей работы с содержимым.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

формируйте ответ в формате json:

```
$arr['a'] = $a;
$arr['b'] = $b;

return json_encode($arr);
```

на стороне клиента:

```
var json = $.parseJSON(response);
$('.link').attr('value', json.a);
```

Comment: Странно, у меня при использовании вышеописанного метода выдает ошибку "Cannot read property 'a' of null", хотя я для примера в переменную записал просто текст $arr['a'] = "test"; 
Проблема по видимому в парсинге, потому как если посмотреть через "echo json_encode($arr);" в консоли браузера в response мы видим: {"a":"test"}. Я наверное не правильно понял.

Comment: Решил проблему. Не знал что при добавление dataType:"json" Jquery сам парсит содержимое ответа.